# DeadLock DbContext Concurrent Transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1

[image]

Hi please see the deadlock graph portion in above image.I have two transactions that update the same table and one of them is long transaction that update that table (same row) 5 times but the other transaction updates that table only once and is a small transaction of two DB hits .Its logically true from the deadlock graph that both the transaction have X lock on different rows and attempting to get U lock . I cant understand why the shorter transaction acquire X lock though it hasn't fired update query yet (as it is the update query that causes deadlock this means it isn't fired yet ). Any help will be highly appericiable. 
1) I am using isolation level read committed
2) I cant understand how the second/first transaction can get X lock while the other transaction already got it on some row.I read that on Update query first U lock is applied and then is upgraded to X lock for that particular updated row.Now when one transaction has X lock then how another transaction can have U lock as during table scan (to determine the row to be updated) it can not read the row that has X lock by other transaction.3) Both the transaction updates one different row of same table.Any possible Solution at DB level without changing Isolation Level.

Comment: The classic answer here is: take the locks in the same order; this might involve issuing a select, perhaps with UPDLOCK. Not sure if that is possible with EF though.

Comment: Use SQL profiler to see what commands are executed during transactions.

Comment: yes I am using EF and its not possible to use lock hint unless we send query through ExecuteStoreCommand @Marc .

Comment: Its only update Command @Ladislav. Is it possible for a transaction to put U Lock if another transaction got X lock on the same table?

Comment: Update command results in X lock and no other transaction (with your isolation level) can use that record until transaction holding X lock is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant understand how the second/first transaction can get X lock
>   while the other transaction already got it on some row.

That is magic behind databases and their performance. The locks can be issued on different levels and if the second transaction didn't use table scan it could issue X lock without conflicting with the first transaction. It is possible that records for update where searched using index and table scan didn't happen so there can be multiple concurrent X locks in your table.

> I read that on Update query first U lock is applied and then is
>   upgraded to X lock for that particular updated row.

No. Update should use X lock on the record directly. U lock must be forced by your read query which reads data to be udpated (that is what @Marc mentioned in his comment). As you already know EF doesn't support this because it cannot use hints.

Comment: Thanks alot these are very useful suggestions. yes iam not using any UPDLOCK hint .And when i see Locks list by using Select * from sys.dm_tran_Locks the locks applied are only X at key level and IX at page level but then why in Deadlock graph it shows both the transaction are waiting to put U lock.

Comment: That is something you must find in executed commands. Deadlock graph should show that also.

Comment: After IX lock is applied to updating Table X KeyLocks are applied to sys.sysconvgroup, sys.sysdesend